# How do I know if the Bitcoin page has been hijacked

Tags: security

With so many hackers hijacking websites these days, what do I look for to show me that I'm not on a hijacked page?

Comment: Bitcoin page for what? On what website? There is no "official Bitcoin website" or "official Bitcoin page".

Comment: Assuming you're referring to bitcoin.org, the short answer is you really can't tell if the adversary knows what they're doing. You can't rely on the certificate authority (CA) system to only hand certificates to the real bitcoin.org domain owner (they screw up often). Furthermore, there's no binary transparency scheme to allow Bitcoin developers to actively monitor all published Bitcoin binaries. So you might download a completely malicious binary (see https://bitcoin.org/en/alert/2016-08-17-binary-safety). Welcome to the Internet! :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to cryptocurrenty. Any website can be spoofed, so the answer would simply be generic information on how to browse the web safely.

Answer (score 0):

First, there isn't any one bitcoin site, but hijackers often try to setup phishing attacks on cryptocurrency sites to get you to enter information they can use to steal your coin (as [happened with EtherDelta this week](https://www.coinwire.com/etherdelta-cautions-users-of-malicious-attacks)).

Generally speaking, look for the green lock icon in your browser. If it isn't there, don't open continue. Best to also check the actual certificate by clicking on that green lock to ensure the certificate is from a well known [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority). Also generally a good idea to watch the twitter account associated with the site. For example, in EtherDelta's case they started tweeting about the issue pretty quickly once they were aware. And if in doubt, don't open it and tweat to the twitter account associated with the site just to make sure all is well.

**If you see a "self-signed" certificate Do not open the site!**